# Does speed affect friction in fluids? If yes, how?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, friction, drag, viscosity

If a solid body is moving through a fluid, does its speed has any effect on the drag force felt by it?

Comment: Drag force is proportional to velocity squared.  And note - your question seems to be a "yes or no" type question.  I posted a comment rather than an answer because I suspect that you are interested in something more specific.  If so, please add more detail to the question.

Comment: Yes. In general for low speeds the drag  will be proportional to the velocity, while for high speeds to the velocity squared.

Answer (score 0):

Provided that the terminal velocity is not yet reached, drag force is directly proportional to speed. That's the real deal. You can check this out anywhere and you'll find this to be the case.

Answer (score 0):

Drag force is proportional to speed for laminar flows (low *reynolds number*) and proportional to speed squared for turbulent flows (high *reynolds number*).